# createContainer does not receive data after route transitions (React Router)

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'm using `React`, `Meteor` and `React Router` for a large app.

When I navigate back in the browser history and even when I go forward the data provided by `createContainer` seems to disappear. So far I tried everything, but this problem persists. Do any of you know why this happens? How to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Everything is fine if I force a full page refresh.

One of my components' exports:

```
export default createContainer( ( params ) => {
  const subs = {}
  subs.image = Meteor.subscribe('contents.images');
  subs.provider = Meteor.subscribe('contentProviders.images');

  const data = {}
  data.image = CloudinaryImageContent.findOne({ _id: params.match.params.id });
  data.provider = CloudinaryProvider.findOne();

  return { subs, data }
}, ImageContentEditPage);
```

In my wrapped component I'm just running a `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps = ({data}) => {
  this.setState({provider: data.provider, image: data.image});
}
```

Comment: if you got result in console.log(subs) ?

Comment: If I navigate to the page using Link or a history.push, everything is fine, once I hit the back button the previous data disappears, the same happens if I hit the next button (browser's).

Comment: Please log something in createContainer and check. createContainer should definitely run on coming back to the route. 
From the looks of it, I would say that your subscription is changing due to some reason. Try to figure out the reason.

Comment: `subs` is undefined. That's why my data is disappearing. Do you guys have any idea of why this happens? This is a very weird behavior.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is not firing once I return to the previous route using the browser history navigation buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific scenario I ended up using `componentDidMount` with some basic validation for data availability.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  const { data } = this.props;
  this.setState({provider: data.provider || {}, image: data.image || {}});
}
```

That did the job.